# VBA EXCEL - If clause excluding values

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code:

```
If Left("Z" & i, 1) <> "B" Then
If (Left("Z" & i, 2) <> "VL") And (Left("Z" & i, 2) <> "VP") Then
    Range("AX" & i).Value = "out of scope"
    Else
    Range("AX" & i).Value = "needs  checking"
    End If
End If
Next I
```

For some reason for values different than B, VL and VP the macro is assigning "out of scope" text instead of "needs checking". Why is that? What can be the solution?

Comment: well, it's not B and it's not VL and it's not VP. .... your code says "out of scope" in that instance ..... what were you expecting?

Comment: If I am not wrong `Left("Z" & i, 1)` should be `Left(Range("A" & i), 1)` and likewise `Left(Range("Z" & i), 2)`.

Comment: Hi Jsotola, the problem was that even if it was for example "VP" the macro still assigned "out of scope". But its solved now :)

Comment: that is not what you said in your question